# Loading intersections consolidated graphs

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

To get the right connected components, I projected a graph then use `osmnx.simplification.consolidate_intersections` to consolidate intersections.

```
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx 
%matplotlib inline
cities = {'Copenhagen':'Copenhagen Municipality, Denmark'}

G1=ox.graph.graph_from_place('Copenhagen Municipality, Denmark', simplify=False, retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=True, which_result=None, buffer_dist=None,clean_periphery=True, custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway"]')

G11=ox.simplification.consolidate_intersections(ox.project_graph(G1, to_crs='EPSG:3812'), tolerance=15, rebuild_graph=True, dead_ends=True, reconnect_edges=True)
G2==ox.project_graph(G11, to_crs='EPSG:4326')

ox.io.save_graphml(G2, filepath='data/Copenhagen_bike.graphml', gephi=True, encoding='utf-8')
print('Copenhagen bike_net saved')
```

I saved `G1` as GraphML file, but when I tried to load `Copenhagen_bike.graphml`, it would come error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '14-1' ".
```

I wonder how to load the file to get a graph with no error.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67228896/how-to-load-intersections-consolidated-graphs

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67237005/7321942